# Repairers keep extracting energy

Tags: javascript, screeps

I started to play Screeps> yesterday and I tried to make my own **"Repairers Script"**! But I failed and I had to use one script from internet..
The problem is that when the Repairers haven't got job to do, they stay next to the energy source extracting even when their are full.. I tried to modify the code but I'm not sure if it will keeps working..
So I'll paste the code here:

```js
var roleRepairer = {

    /** @param {Creep} creep **/
    run: function(creep) {

        if (creep.memory.working == true && creep.carry.energy == 0) {
            // switch state
            creep.memory.working = false;
        }
        // if creep is harvesting energy but is full
        else if (creep.memory.working == false && creep.carry.energy == creep.carryCapacity) {
            // switch state
            creep.memory.working = true;
        }

        // if creep is supposed to repair something
        if (creep.memory.working == true) {
            // find closest structure with less than max hits
            // Exclude walls because they have way too many max hits and would keep
            // our repairers busy forever. We have to find a solution for that later.
            var structure = creep.pos.findClosestByPath(FIND_STRUCTURES, {

                filter: (s) => s.hits < s.hitsMax && s.structureType != STRUCTURE_WALL
            });

            // if we find one
            if (structure != undefined) {
                // try to repair it, if it is out of range
                if (creep.repair(structure) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                    // move towards it
                    creep.moveTo(structure);
                }
            }
            // if we can't fine one
            else {
                // look for construction sites
                roleBuilder.run(creep);
            }
        }
        // if creep is supposed to harvest energy from source
        else {
            // find closest source
            var source = creep.pos.findClosestByPath(FIND_SOURCES_ACTIVE);
            // try to harvest energy, if the source is not in range
            if (creep.harvest(source) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                // move towards the source
                creep.moveTo(source);
            }

        } 
    }
};

module.exports = roleRepairer;
```

I hope you can help me to learn a bit more about this wonderful game!
Much aprpeciated!

Comment: The home page of screeps.com has an image of a [snippet of code](https://screeps.com/img/slide1.png) that seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: After reading this code, I would expect the repairer creep to remain next to the source until either a structure needs to be repaired, or (presuably based on the name roleBuilder) a construction site is created. What are you expecting the repairers to do when they are full of energy but there is nothing to repair?

Comment: I would like to send them to spawn or to another empty place.. But I don't really know where I should declare it in this code ..

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to replace the line that calls the `roleBuilder.run` function. In the example below, 12 and 42 are the x and y cooridinates of some empty space. Alternatively you can place a flag and have them move to it. When and if you have creeps in multiple room you will likely need to rework this solution.

```
var roleRepairer = {

    /** @param {Creep} creep **/
    run: function(creep) {

        if (creep.memory.working == true && creep.carry.energy == 0) {
            // switch state
            creep.memory.working = false;
        }
        // if creep is harvesting energy but is full
        else if (creep.memory.working == false && creep.carry.energy == creep.carryCapacity) {
            // switch state
            creep.memory.working = true;
        }

        // if creep is supposed to repair something
        if (creep.memory.working == true) {
            // find closest structure with less than max hits
            // Exclude walls because they have way too many max hits and would keep
            // our repairers busy forever. We have to find a solution for that later.
            var structure = creep.pos.findClosestByPath(FIND_STRUCTURES, {

                filter: (s) => s.hits < s.hitsMax && s.structureType != STRUCTURE_WALL
            });

            // if we find one
            if (structure != undefined) {
                // try to repair it, if it is out of range
                if (creep.repair(structure) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                    // move towards it
                    creep.moveTo(structure);
                }
            }
            // if we can't fine one
            else {
                // look for construction sites
                //roleBuilder.run(creep);
                creep.moveTo(12, 42); //!!!HERE!!!
            }
        }
        // if creep is supposed to harvest energy from source
        else {
            // find closest source
            var source = creep.pos.findClosestByPath(FIND_SOURCES_ACTIVE);
            // try to harvest energy, if the source is not in range
            if (creep.harvest(source) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                // move towards the source
                creep.moveTo(source);
            }

        } 
    }
};

module.exports = roleRepairer;
```

Comment: Hello Benjamin! that was what I needed, thanks a lot you all for your suggestions!